# Vue tree view with draggable nodes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm building tree component in Vue js, and now I'm having difficulties with implementing drag and drop in Tree component. The problem is I do not know where to start, I have looked around the code on GitHub but I could not understand how it is really functioning

I have this code till know:

Tree component:

```
<template>
  <div class="tree">
      <div @click.prevent="selectItem">
        {{ item.label }}
        <span class="icon" @click.stop="toggleNode">{{ expanded && isFolder ? '-' : '+' }}</span>
      </div>
      <ul v-show="expanded" v-if="isFolder">
        <cmp-tree class="item" :key="index" v-for="(child, index) in item.children"
                  :current-item="currentItem"
                  :item="child"> </cmp-tree>
      </ul>
  </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
  import Vue, { PropType } from 'vue';

  export default Vue.extend({
    name: 'CmpTree', // vue component name
    props: {
      item: Object as PropType<any>,
      depth: { default: () => 0, type: Number },
      currentItem: Number,
      value: { default: () => null, type: Array }
    },
    data() {
      return {
          expanded: false as boolean,
          showContext: false as boolean,
      };
    },
    methods: {
      toggleNode(): void {
          this.expanded = !this.expanded;
      },
      selectItem() {
          console.log(this.item);
      },
    },
    computed: {
      isFolder(): void {
        return this.item.children && this.item.children.length
      },
    },
  });
</script>
```

Main Component for Displaying Tree:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <CmpTree v-for="(item, index) in items"
             class="item"
             :current-item="currentItem"
             :item="item"
             :key="index"
             contextmenu>
    </CmpTree>
  </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
import CmpTree from '@/components/CmpTree.vue';

export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'ServeDev',
  components: {
    CmpTree
  },
  data(): any {
    return {
      items: [
        {
          label: 'item1',
          children: [
            {
              label: 'item1.1'
            },
            {
              label: 'item1.2',
              children: [
                {
                  label: 'item1.2.1'
                },
                {
                  label: 'item1.2.2'
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          label: 'item2'
        }
      ],
      selectedItems: [],
      currentItem: null,
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Could anyone suggest me some article or simple from where should I start to build up ?

Comment: I wrote a tree component for vue. here are the steps: 1. set the nodes' draggable attributes to true.
2. store the node being dragged in dragstart event handler.
3. do algorithms (get the mouse position, find out where the node is in the tree, and check if it is allowed to drop currently) and display something according to the current situtation in the dragover event handler.
4. drop the node in the drop event handler. my source code:
https://github.com/TinyWisp/twtree

Answer (score 2):

You can use Library called `Vue-draggable`, 
Here's their example of Nested Draggable, similar to what you need.

https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable/blob/master/example/components/nested/nested-test.vue

Hope, this could be helpful.